# How can I remove admob's interstitial ads from this code

Tags: android, android-activity, admob, interstitial

So as it says in the title how can I remove the code for admob interstitial ads from my application? here is the activity.java code with the interstitial code in it I want to remove it and add a different company's ads and I am afraid I might screw something up since I have no coding skill or experience.

Code for `Activity`:

```
    package com.package.example;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import android.media.MediaPlayer;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.res.AssetFileDescriptor;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.KeyEvent;
    import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
    import android.webkit.WebView;
    import com.google.analytics.tracking.android.EasyTracker;
    import com.google.ads.*;
    import com.google.ads.AdRequest.ErrorCode;
    import com.kareem.Cairokee2014.R;

   @SuppressLint({ "SetJavaScriptEnabled", "JavascriptInterface" })
   public class activity extends Activity implements AdListener {
  public  MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
  public WebView webView;
  AssetFileDescriptor afd = null;
  private InterstitialAd interstitial;

  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     // Create the interstitial
        interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this, "1234567890");

        // Create ad request
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();

        // Begin loading your interstitial
        interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);

        // Set Ad Listener to use the callbacks below
        interstitial.setAdListener(this);

        this.webView = ((WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView));
        this.webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        this.webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        this.webView.addJavascriptInterface(this, "activity");
        this.webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
      }

  @Override
  public void onReceiveAd(Ad ad) {
    Log.d("OK", "Received ad");
    if (ad == interstitial) {
      interstitial.show();
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    EasyTracker.getInstance().activityStart(this); // Add this method.
  }

  @Override
  public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    EasyTracker.getInstance().activityStop(this); // Add this method.
  }

  int lastfile;
    public void play(int n) {
        if (lastfile != n && lastfile >= 1) {
            player.stop();
            player = new MediaPlayer();
        }
        lastfile = n;
        try {
            afd = getAssets().openFd("source/"+n+".mp3");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            player.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(),afd.getStartOffset(),afd.getLength());
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            player.prepare();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (!player.isPlaying())
        player.start();
    }

    public void pause() {
        if (player.isPlaying())
        player.pause();
    }

    public void stop() {
        player.stop();
        player = new MediaPlayer();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDismissScreen(Ad arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailedToReceiveAd(Ad arg0, ErrorCode arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onLeaveApplication(Ad arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onPresentScreen(Ad arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

     @Override
        public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                switch(keyCode)
                {
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                    if(webView.canGoBack() == true){
                        webView.goBack();
                    }else{
                        finish();
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
        }
```

Here is the `AndroidManifest` I can't find the part you said I should delete

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.kareem.Cairokee2014"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="true"
android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true"
android:anyDensity="true" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true">

    <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
               android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>

    <activity
        android:name="com.kareem.Cairokee2014.activity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
         android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
                            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                       >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems pretty straight forward. Delete:

```
private InterstitialAd interstitial;

 // Create the interstitial
    interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this, "1234567890");

    // Create ad request
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();

    // Begin loading your interstitial
    interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);

    // Set Ad Listener to use the callbacks below
    interstitial.setAdListener(this);

@Override
public void onReceiveAd(Ad ad) {
Log.d("OK", "Received ad");
if (ad == interstitial) {
  interstitial.show();
}
}
```

Remove these from the `Manifest.xml` :

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
<activity
       android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
       android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
```

Comment: Delete the imports or ctrl+shift+o in eclipse. You'll also need to remove a couple things from the manifest

Comment: I added my manifest code in the question, I didn't find the part you put in the answer. also what do you mean by "Delete the imports" if i press ctrl+shift+o it deletes all of them but aren't the associated with the app or just the interstitial advertisement? also I have banner ad in the app that i want to keep is it okay to do this or would it remove the banner ad? I think the imports have to do with the analytics and the banner admob ad. thanks a ton for your help!

Comment: It's likely that you would want to keep the manifest code if you're still displaying other ads.